# Is it possible to install Ubuntu in Tablets & Smartphones

Tags: tablet, smartphone

I have heard some devices come with Ubuntu installed but is it possible to install it on Tablets and Smartphones that do not have Ubuntu preinstalled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM

From there:

### ARM Processor

ARM is a processor architecture used in a variety of applications, such as:

- Handheld Computers (Nokia n900, n95, etc.)
- Network Devices (Genesi Efika MX Nettop, Wyse T50, CompuLab
  TrimSlice, etc.)
- Project development boards (Beagleboard, Pandaboard, Quickstart,
  etc.) Subnotebooks (Sharp Netwalker, etc.)
- Netbook/Notebooks (Genesi Efika MX Smartbook, Toshiba AC100, etc.)
- Ubuntu targets the ARMv7 and above Application Processor family
  (Cortex A8, A9 and above). Currently the archive supports ARM EABI,
  with an expectation of minimum compliance with the ARMv7+VFP ISA.
  Where possible Ubuntu targets the Thumb2 instruction set.

Limited support for earlier instruction sets (ARMv5t, ARMv6) was available in early releases of the ARM port (jaunty, karmic).

### Status

- Much of the application porting is complete
- Installation images are available for selected boards
- kernels for a variety of sub-architectures are available
- Much of SMP validation complete
- Continued porting and optimization is underway

### Current Images

ARM TEAM

- OMAP: Texas Instruments OMAP
- Tegra (AC100): Thosiba AC100 Nvidia Tegra 2
- IMX53 QuickStart: Freescale IMX53 QuickStart Board
- Server images (for OMAP3/4 so far) ARM/ServerInstall

There's more at their FAQ too, which you can check there too.