# Installing Ubuntu on my android tablet with Cortex-A10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install Ubuntu in Tablets & Smartphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104811/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-in-tablets-smartphones)

Is there any way to install Ubuntu (some version) on my tablet? Its DOMO X3G Slate (Rooted) with Cortex-A10, Mali 400 MP, 8 GB internal. I just wanted to run "natively" and not using emulators or something like that. Can someone help me with step-by-step instructions, as i'm extremely new to this part. It's running ICS currently.
Thanks!
P.S. I never understood the terms kernel, bootstrap, etc (Terms related to that). Can someone  help me with that too?? :)

Comment: AFAIK there's not generic way of Installing Ubuntu into an Android tablet because of the differences between hardware. There are Official ARM images for TI OMAP and there have been images specific for other devices created by users themselves, now if you don't understand the word "Kernel"  I think you're better off not doing anything to your tablet.